# Passing id value of actionlink to javascript function in my Asp.net Mvc Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I have this actionlink in my _alyout.cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linky", "action", "controller", new { id = 1})
```

and this Java script in my Index.cshtml.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        getProductsByDepartmentId(departmentid);

    })


function getProductsByDepartmentId(departmentid) {

    var tbl = $('#productTable');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/GetProductsByDepartmentId?id=' + departmentid,
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        },
        error: function () {

        }

    });

    }
```

My Action method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetProductsByDepartmentId(int id)
        {
            using (context)
            {
                return (PartialView("_ProductList", await context.Products.Where(d => d.Deptid == id).ToListAsync()));
            }

        }
```

How do I do to call my javascriptfunktion from my actionlink. I do I pass value of id in Actionlink to my getProductsByDepartmentId(departmentid) function?
I would be grateful for any help

Comment: What are you trying to do here and when? Your calling `getProductsByDepartmentId(departmentid);` when the page is first loaded but `departmentid` does not exist. Does your page include links for each Department and you want to use ajax to call a method that returns a partial view of Products for that Department?

Comment: You're not defining any way to get `departmentid` value required by the function at first place. Have you want to return partial view from AJAX call with ActionLink? In which way `departmentid` was added to JS function then?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for confusing you, not when page loaded first time. I should not have inside $(document).ready(function (). My page includs links for each Department and I want to use ajax to call a method that returns a partial view of Products for that Department. I have updated my code with HttpGet Action

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Sorry for confusing you, not when page loaded first time. I should not have inside $(document).ready(function (). My page includs links for each Department and I want to use ajax to call a method that returns a partial view of Products for that Department. I have updated my code with HttpGet Action

Comment: Then you just want `<a href="#" class="details" data-id="yourDepartmentID">Details</a>` and the script is `var url = '@Url.Action("GetProductsByDepartmentId"); $('.details').click(function() { tbl.load(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }); });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. Do you mean this one in my _layout.cshtml <a href="#" class="details" data-id="(for example 1)">Details</a>  and this one in my Index.cshtml JavaScript var url = '@Url.Action("GetProductsByDepartmentId")'; $('.details').click(function() { tbl.load(url, { id: $(this).data('id') }); }); ? Nothing happen ...

Comment: Then you have other errors as well. Debug your script.

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Greate Thank you